# Problema con los collapsible de jquery mobile y ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-mobile

Buenas tardes.

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para móviles con jquery mobile y tengo un problema con los elementos collapsible.

Hago una llamada ajax al servidor para obtener datos, y si la respuesta es correcta lo que quiero es insertar tantos elementos collapsibles como respuestas del servidor.

Codigo html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="paginaListado">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Listado</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="seccionListadoMaterial"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Código javascript:

```
$("#seccionListadoMaterial").html("");

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/listadoMaterial.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        for(var i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){
            $("#seccionListado").append("<div data-role='collapsible'><h3>Esto es lo de fuera</h3><p>Y esto lo de dentro</p></div>");
        }
    }
}); 
$.mobile.changePage('#paginaListado');
```

Si la hago como muestro aquí arriba, se ve de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio, si en vez de hacer el for dentro del succes de ajax lo hago fuera, se ve ok:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito hacerlo dentro de la llamada ajax para poder poner al collapsible el texto que recibo del servidor.

He probado a cambiar el tema, pero nada, también he probado a hacerlo "collapsible-set" pero lo mismo.

¿Por qué puede estar pasando?

Saludos.

Comment: Al margen de la respuesta recibida, ten en cuenta que `$("#seccionListado")`, esta mal. Debería ser $("#seccionListadoMaterial")

Comment: Eso fue un fallo a la hora de copiar y pegar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se debe a que en la carga inicial de la página, automáticamente todos los elemento con atributo `data-role="collapsible"` son convertidos a `collapsible`.

### Solución:

Cuando los elementos son creados posterior a la carga inicial (`eg: asincrónica`) debes crearlos manualmente.

### Demo:

```js
$(function() {

  // AQUI Ejemplo de carga asincrónica
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $container = $("#seccionListadoMaterial");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      $container.append("<div data-role='collapsible'><h3>Esto es lo de fuera</h3><p>Y esto lo de dentro</p></div>");
    }
    
    // AQUI Creamos manualmente los Collapsible
    $container.find('[data-role="collapsible"]').collapsible();
  }, 500);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-alpha.1.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="page" id="paginaListado">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Listado</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <div id="seccionListadoMaterial"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola buenos días Marcos. Increíble. Es lo que buscaba. Me ha funcionado a la perfección. Te lo agradezco mucho de verdad. Saludos.